# OpenGL, Zooming out in a tile-based game

Tags: opengl, 2d, zooming

If you've got a 2D tile based game, and you want to allow the player to zoom out (and see more of the world), how would you implement it?

Normally I'd only render the tiles that were visible within the game's glOrtho view, but if I'm allowing zooming then the floating point precision wrecks havoc on trying to get everything aligned (believe me it's alot harder than it sounds). Is the correct solution to render the entire world, and let OpenGL handle the worry about not rendering what's not visible?

Comment: Why does it need to be aligned?

Comment: I mean, aligning it so that while things are zooming in/out, the position of objects do not jitter.

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with sending to render slightly bigger area, that will for sure fit into your view, yet not big enough as the whole world.

Your question does not mention if your 2D allows rotation of camera. Visible area can be represented as a bounding rect in tile space:

```
Width_In_Tiles := RoundUp(View_Width_In_Px / Single_Tile_Width_In_Px * Zoom);
Left_Margin := Center_Of_View - RoundUp(Width_In_Tiles / 2);
Right_Margin := Center_Of_View + RoundUp(Width_In_Tiles / 2);

//same for vertical axis

//Naive example
for K := Top_Margin to Bottom_Margin do
  for I := Left_Margin to Right_Margin do
    RenderTilesAndObjects(I, K);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would render the tiles to a texture and then render the entire scene with one quad that's one tile-width larger than your screen. Transform that one quad as your global position modulo the tile width. Then opengl's built in texture filtering will take care of jitter. This has potential speed benefits, too. Rather than render all the tiles on screen each frame, you'd only have to render the tiles along the perimeter of your texture that become newly visible, and occasionally (when the edge of the screen crosses a tile boundary) you'd have to blit the contents of your texture.

For zooming, you could use a similar idea but with mipmapping.